# ReactJS onChange event handler

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs, onchange, handle

I've got some confusion with React's event handler

I have a component like this, with `handleChange` handling `onChange` event:

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
        return {word:''};
    },
    handleChange: function(event){
        this.setState({word:event.target.value});
        alert(this.state.word);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div style={{width:'100%',position:'0',backgroundColor:'darkOrange'}}>
                <div className="header">
                    <h1>MOVIE</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="searchForm">
                    <input className="searchField" onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.word} type="text" placeholder="Enter search term"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

It does work, but not the way I expect. In textfield, when I type the first character, it alerts empty string, when the second character is typed, it alerts a string with only first character, and so on, with string length of n, it alerts the string with n-1 length

What did I do wrong here? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this,

Js:

```
   this.setState({word:event.target.value}, function() {
    alert(this.state.word)
   });
```

Working [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/molozekemi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with state handling inside React.

I can come with two options to handle it.

Either:

```
handleChange: function(event) {
  this.setState({word: event.target.value});
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert(this.state.word);
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Or:

```
alertCurrentValue() {
  alert(this.state.word);
},
render: function () {
  this.alertCurrentValue();
  return ( ... )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Praveen Raj's answer is definitely the right way to go. Here is the documentation I found from the [official React website](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) on why you should access this.state inside the callback rather than right after setState():

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.